# How to use the same button to navigate to different routes in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have made a button in a separate class and was wondering is there a way to navigate to different screens using the same button class I made? The plan is to navigate to different pages by using the onPress() function.

```
 import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 import 'package:senior_design/View/Helm.dart';

 class Button extends StatelessWidget {

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {


// TODO: implement build
return SizedBox(
width: 100,
  height: 100,
  child:
  RaisedButton(
    //alignment: Alignment(100.0, 100.0),

       child: Row(

         children: <Widget>[

           Text("Button"),

         ]
       ),
      onPressed: () {

          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Helm()),
          );

      }
  ),
);
}


}
```

Comment: If there is a condition you can use ternary operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good afternoon,

I believe that if you can pass a method as a parameter for you to be able to navigate on different screens.

```
// Creating a custom buttom with a method passed by parameter
class Button extends StatelessWidget {
  final VoidCallback onPress;
  final double width;
  final double height;

  Button({this.onPress, this.width, this.height});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: width,
      height: height,
      child: RaisedButton(
        color: Colors.pink,
        textColor: Colors.white,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
          Text("Button"),
        ],),
        onPressed: onPress,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I did an example on https://dartpad.dev/42c49f8cd0c8dbd834525eb41630d599 for you.

I hope it helps you.
hugs.

Comment: Thanks for the example it really helped!!

Answer (score 2):

You can include the function you want to be executed, or the page you want to show, as a variable that you set for your custom button widget:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:senior_design/View/Helm.dart';

class Button extends StatelessWidget {

  // include this argument you pass in when the button is constructed
  final Widget pageToShow;

  Button({this.pageToShow}) : assert(pageToShow != null);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return SizedBox(
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      child: RaisedButton(
          //alignment: Alignment(100.0, 100.0),

          child: Row(children: <Widget>[
            Text("Button"),
          ]),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => pageToShow,)
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a pro move. I like it